# How to import database backed up in commerical version of DB2 8.9 to free DB2 10 ExpressC Edition

Tags: db2

Please let me know the steps on importing DB2 database exported from Commerical Version (DB2 8/9 ) to free DB2 ExpressC Edition(10).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are trying to restore into a DB2 Express C running in the 'same platform'(Same OS and same/higher bit level), you should not face any issue with the normal 'RESTORE' command.
If it is otherwise, it gets a little trickier. You can use the 'db2look' command to copy the schema(DDLs) creation SQLs and then run them in new machine to recreate the schema. Then you should use 'db2move' to move the user data present in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in DB2 there is no limitation about database size in free edition. Just CPU limitation exist. So there won't be any issue about porting you database to free edition.

Here is step by step way to do it. On old system:

```
# db2look -d DBNAME -e -o DBNAME.DDL
# db2move DBNAME export
```

After moving all generated files to new system, issue these commands on new system:

```
# db2 CREATE DATABASE DBNAME
# db2 -tvf DBNAME.DDL
# db2move DBNAME IMPORT
```

That's all.